# " There is already an object named 'Author' in the database."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the following Relational Diagram in Sql Power Architect (as I was told to do at school). The next step presented in the course is to use Forward Engineer to get the script and paste it in Sql Management Server using new Query. I get this Error " There is already an object named 'Author' in the database." I have no knowledge of what it means or how should be corrected. I can not go to the next steps in the course if I ca`t execute without errrors. 
( I read previous asked questions but I am not sure the answers apply to my script.)

```
CREATE TABLE Author (
                Author_ID INT NOT NULL,
                Author_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT Author_ID PRIMARY KEY (Author_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Publisher (
                Publisher_ID INT NOT NULL,
                Publisher_Name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
                Address VARCHAR(100),
                CONSTRAINT Publisher_ID PRIMARY KEY (Publisher_ID)
)
CREATE UNIQUE  NONCLUSTERED INDEX Publisher_idx
 ON Publisher
 ( Publisher_ID )


CREATE TABLE Book (
                ISBN CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
                Title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
                Price REAL NOT NULL,
                DateAdded DATETIME,
                Pages INT,
                DescriptionSummary TEXT,
                Publisher_ID INT NOT NULL,
                Author_ID INT NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT ISBN PRIMARY KEY (ISBN)
)
CREATE UNIQUE  NONCLUSTERED INDEX Book_idx
 ON Book
 ( Title )

CREATE UNIQUE  CLUSTERED INDEX Book_idx11
 ON Book
 ( ISBN )

CREATE UNIQUE  CLUSTERED INDEX Book_idx2
 ON Book
 ( ISBN )

CREATE UNIQUE  CLUSTERED INDEX Book_idx3
 ON Book
 ( ISBN )


CREATE TABLE Book_Genre (
                ISBN CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
                Genre_ID_sq_1 INT NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT ISBN PRIMARY KEY (ISBN, Genre_ID_sq_1)
)

CREATE TABLE Genre (
                Genre_ID INT NOT NULL,
                ISBN CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
                Genre VARCHAR(44) NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT ID PRIMARY KEY (Genre_ID, ISBN)
)
CREATE UNIQUE  NONCLUSTERED INDEX Genre_idx
 ON Genre
 ( Genre_ID )


ALTER TABLE Book ADD CONSTRAINT Author_Book_fk
FOREIGN KEY (Author_ID)
REFERENCES Author (Author_ID)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION

ALTER TABLE Book ADD CONSTRAINT Publisher_Book_fk
FOREIGN KEY (Publisher_ID)
REFERENCES Publisher (Publisher_ID)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION

ALTER TABLE Book_Genre ADD CONSTRAINT Book_Book_Genre_fk
FOREIGN KEY (ISBN)
REFERENCES Book (ISBN)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION

ALTER TABLE Genre ADD CONSTRAINT Book_Genre_Genre_fk
FOREIGN KEY (ISBN, Genre_ID)
REFERENCES Book_Genre (ISBN, Genre_ID_sq_1)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

[image]

Comment: Since `Author` is the first item you create, I'd wager the table already exists, having been previously created by another run of your script. I don't know sql server, but either there is a `create or replace` syntax or you should `drop` the table (or the whole `schema`) beforehand.

Comment: `IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Author', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Author; ` for all tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you have already created Author table. Now you can ALTER it or DROP it. If you are using Microsoft SQL Server Management studio you can just right-click on your table -> select *Script Table as* -> *DROP And CREATE Table to*-> new query editor window. This will create sql code for dropping the table and creating new one. Same as this code below.

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Author]
GO

CREATE TABLE Author (
            Author_ID INT NOT NULL,
            Author_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT Author_ID PRIMARY KEY (Author_ID)
)
GO
```

However, if you drop the table you will lose the data from Author table. Maybe just rename it in Management Studio to Author1 if you don't feel confident enough. Also you can see what else is using your table by using stored procedure called sp_depends.

```
sp_depends Author;
```

It will tell you who else needs table Author to function normally. You can also try using it with other things and not just tables. It's one useful little thing for making sure you won't cause too much problems before dropping something.